# Passing Customized Parameter in UNIX Shell Scripting

Tags: unix

I have parameters named "Country" and "City"

The usual method of running the script is
**Script.ksh "India" "Mumbai"..
..it will run ok.**

But, My requirement is...I want to run this script as
**Script.ksh -Country "India" -City "Delhi"**

Culd any one please get me out of this

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: is `getopt` available as a command on your system?

Comment: Could you please give one example...using this command?
I have no idea on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample use:

```
#!/bin/sh

setopt() {
  if [ -n "$1" -a -n "$2" ]; then
    optname=opt_${1#--}
    optval="\"$2\""
    eval $optname="$optval"
    shift
    shift
    setopt "$@"
  fi
}

eval setopt $(getopt -a -l city:,country: -o "" -- "$@")

echo "City is ${opt_city}"
echo "Country is ${opt_country}"
```

You could use the same technique without getopt, but getopt has the added benefit of normalizing names and recognizing abbreviations (at least GNU getopt does).

```
$ ./opttest -city "New Delhi" -country India
City is New Delhi
Country is India

$ ./opttest -ci "New Delhi" -co India
City is New Delhi
Country is India
```